# What to test if working with already mature code base with no tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I work at a company on a product with a fairly mature code base.  Rails Api with Angular heavy front end.  Currently we do not test.

I would like to know what is the best strategy for starting to test.

Is trying to retrofit tests for already written code a good/bad idea?

If good, what is a good approach to doing this?

If bad, is it still a good idea to write tests for future code?

And in (real) short, what are the pros/cons of testing? I welcome any cogent answers for why not to test, as the prevailing opinion (mine, admittedly included) seems to be very strongly in favor of testing.

Finally, any advice on testing JS and best frameworks/tools to do that is welcome as well.

Comment: Here's an [article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/09/advanced-testing-and-debugging-in-angularjs.html) to help you making your own opinion about testing, why?, when?, how?... To test an Angular app, you should take a look at [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html) for unit-testing, and [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) for e2e/integration-testing as they are developped and recommanded by the Angular Team ;)

Comment: Start with integration (some form of selenium or similar) tests, followed by refactoring to allow small, simple unit tests.

Comment: Also: Why do I write tests? Because it gives me confidence that new code I introduce does not break existing features. As a result I can deploy often and stress free.